# Need to pass arguments to dev_err macro

Tags: c

Have an wrapper function **xxxTRACE(uint loglevel, const char* message, ...)**, need to check the loglevel value and use **dev_err, dev_warn and ... macros**. Since for ex: **dev_err** signature is **dev_err(struct device *dev, char *fmt, args...)**, I am able to pass the message string without any errors, but unable to pass the arguments, tried passing as **dev_err(dev, message, ...)**, **dev_err(dev, message, __VA_ARGS__)**, getting error **"expected expression before '...'"**. Please do let me know how to pass the arguments. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is the same signature as printf. You pass the message in the same format: e.g.:

```
dev_err("Hello World\n");
dev_warn("I'm getting old, I'm now: %d years old", my_age);
```

`

Comment: The question is about forwarding varargs.

Comment: You can't forward varargs to a macro. You can to a function. What is the reason to wrap a macro with a function? It doesn't make any sense ... you'd use a macro to be inlined .. but once you put a function around it that is no longer the case. The question wasn't very clear with the code samples which is why I misinterpreted it.

Comment: So I can't pass varargs from a function to a macro is it?

Answer (score 0):

I normally use macros for this where `__VA_ARGS__` are available. I am not quite sure which C standard supports this. It works for me in gnu99, maybe it will in gnu89.

```
#define xxxTRACE(loglevel, message, ...) do { \
    if (loglevel == 0) { \
        dev_err(dev, message, __VA_ARGS__) \
    } else { \
        dev_warn(dev, message, __VA_ARGS__) \
    } \
} while (0)
```